# Fill UIView from bottom to top

Tags: ios, swift

I have this [UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrBea.png) that right now has that static light gray filled, I need it to fill based on a number I give it that comes from an API. I tried a couple of ways but don't work for me. What's the simplest approach to this? Doesn't have to have fancy effects or anything, just a simple animation that slowly fills up the circle by giving it a number.

The API returns Int that are 0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90 and 100.
So given those numbers I have to use them to fill the circle. They are basically percentages. So 10 should make the circle fill 10%.

This is the code that I have right now, it's in the same file as the `ViewController` but I don't think it's the best way, or at least it's not working because when I try to update the `coeff` it doesn't do it.

```
class BadgeView: UIView {
    
    private let fillView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
    private var fillHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    private(set) var coeff: CGFloat = 0.2 {
        didSet {
            updateFillViewFrame()
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        setupView()
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        setupView()
    }
    
    public func setupView() {
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.height / 2.0
        layer.masksToBounds = true
        fillView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 220.0/255.0, green: 220.0/255.0, blue: 220.0/255.0, alpha: 0.4)
        fillView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false // ensure autolayout works
        addSubview(fillView)
        
        // pin view to leading, trailing and bottom to the container view
        fillView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        fillView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        fillView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        // save the constraint to be changed later
        fillHeightConstraint = fillView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 0)
        fillHeightConstraint.isActive = true
        updateFillViewFrame()
    }
    
    public func updateFillViewFrame() {
        fillHeightConstraint.constant = bounds.height * coeff // change the constraint value
        layoutIfNeeded() // update the layout when a constraint changes
    }
    
    public func setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat, animated: Bool) {
        if animated {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, animations:{ () -> Void in
                self.coeff = coeff
            })
        } else {
            self.coeff = coeff
        }
    }
}
```

The exact thing that it's not working is here:

```
if let ElapsedPercentual:Int = JSON.value(forKeyPath: "ResponseEntity.ElapsedPercentual") as? Int {
            porcentaje = ElapsedPercentual
            print(porcentaje)
    >>>     BadgeView().setCoeff(coeff: CGFloat(porcentaje)/100, animated: true)
```

That line isn't actually updating the coeff, so it's always 0.2 as previously setted. Instead it should go from 0.0 to 1.0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Could you please post the code you have tried and what exactly is not working?

Comment: There you go!..

Comment: Your code has no issue. What is not working for you?

Comment: I added a brief explanation, at the bottom. If you need anything else to better understand the problem, let me know!

Answer (score 0):

First of all: I strongly suggest using a framework for build constrains programatically. Something like [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).

Using a basic setup where you have a `UIView` (Container) that contains another `UIView` (myView). Where `myView` is used to fill the `Container`.
You could use the following code (didn't fully test that though) to animate the constraint and have the effect of filling up the `container` with the `myView`

```swift
self.myView.snp_makeConstraints { make in
    make.left.right.bottom.equalTo(self.myContainer)
    make.height.equalTo(0)
}

let newPercentage = 10
UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3) {
    self.myView.snp_updateConstraints { make in
        make.height.equalTo(self.myContainer.frame.height / 100 * newPercentage)
    }
    self.myView.superview.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: I think the using of frameworks for constraints is an overkill. Setting up layout constraints with swift directly is easy and readable. Using a framework means carrying the burden of bugs made by others and keeping a dependency up-to-date. A personal opinion, of course.

Comment: Depending on your scenario it truly might be more feasible to keep it vanilla. Personally I do favor using native functionality over external frameworks (which under the hood still use normal code) as long as those frameworks don't provide more comfort in use. Reinventing the wheel is not often needed. `SnapKit` in particular to me is by far easier to read, doesn't clutter with long, hard to read lines like vanilla (which also can be a problem when you use `swiftlint` -> line_length_violation) and is shorter to write in most cases. All depends on your use-case of course.

Comment: Thank you for your response! But this doesn't solve my problem :(